# Is it possible to make an exception for CommandInvokeError without an error handler?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

It's not finished but I'm adding a poll feature to my bot. But I want to be able to do something if no question or options are provided. I don't want to make an error handler because I feel it is extremely far beyond what I know.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def poll(ctx, *, msg):
        try:
            split_msg = msg.split(";")
            question = split_msg[0]
            option1 = split_msg[1]
            option2 = split_msg[2]
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Question", description=question)
            embed.add_field(name="Option 1", value=option1, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Option 2", value=option2, inline=True)
            error = discord.Embed(title=":warning: Incorrect Syntax!", description="Usage: {}poll <question>; <option1>; <option2>".format(prefix))
            await bot.say(embed=embed)
        except CommandInvokeError:
            print("CommandInvokeError")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `CommandInvokeError` is the exception that is raised by the bot invoking the command when command execution raises any uncaught error.  Your code won't raise a `CommandInvokeError`, so you can't catch it.  If you examine the full error message, you'll likely see that your `CommandInvokeError` is being caused by another error, which you can catch.

Comment: Thank you for your help